# Trim spaces in string - LTRIM RTRIM not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried this code -

```
UPDATE Table
SET Name = RTRIM(LTRIM(Name))
```

Data type of Name is `varchar(25)`

None of the leading and trailing spaces get removed. When I copy-paste one such `Name`, 
i get this -

```
"big dash" "space symbol" ABC001
```

Why is this happening and how do trim the spaces ?

**EDIT -**

The question has already been answered. I found one more table with this problem. I get 
"- value" when i copy a column of a row. When I press the enter key at end of this copy-pasted value, i see more dashes. See image below -

[image: Weird symbols]

Comment: Datatype of Name column please? I guess that could be `CHAR` means, it is fixed in length. So the rest other than input text is filled with spaces??!! And FYI.. I didn't down vote!

Comment: What is this -1 for  ?

Comment: @OracleUser - Data type of Name is varchar(25)

Comment: `select convert(varbinary, Name) from table`.. see the hex value in it.. may be some non readable spl characters.

Comment: @OracleUser - I saw a huge hex character 0xA0...etc. I added a where name = 'ABC001' clause in your query and got no result. When I copy pasted the name as is, ie ' ABC001', I got the hex code. What does this mean ?

Comment: SO, you are having junks inside, as I guessed.. you may have to write some functions to remove them.. Please refer [here](http://iso30-sql.blogspot.com/2010/10/remove-non-printable-unicode-characters.html). To remove all such characters.

Comment: @OracleUser - It worked perfectly. You can put it as an answer if you wish. Thanks.

Comment: For my situation, I was selecting some columns into a temp table, then scripting out the table. I never went to go back to see the data type for what should have been varchar were, in fact, char fields.

Comment: This was happening to me.  The answers below helped fixed the data.  The reason why I was getting an extra carriage return & newline was because I was copying values out of Excel cells and pasting them into the table via MS SSMS's Edit Rows feature.  Excel was adding the extra characters during the copy.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I suspect, some non readable(Non-ascii characters) inside the name column, that might not get removed as part of `TRIM` calls.

```
select convert(varbinary, Name) from table
```

Reading the `HEX` output from above query should reveal the same.

Kindly read [this](http://iso30-sql.blogspot.com/2010/10/remove-non-printable-unicode-characters.html) to find how to write functions to remove such characters.

Answer (score 75):

Kindly use below query it will remove space new line etc..

```
select LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Name, CHAR(10), CHAR(32)),CHAR(13), CHAR(32)),CHAR(160), CHAR(32)),CHAR(9),CHAR(32))))
```

Comment: Simple yet effective for my issue.

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Great answer, saves time.

Answer (score 14):

It is a frequent occurrence that we must remove leading and trailing whitespaces from a string before additional processing or sending it to another layer in an application. We can’t always control how the data is entered. The data might come from another system, a data conversion, an old application, EDI, Excel, or from an application which had poor quality control. In some of those cases, a whitespace might not be entered or saved in the system as character 32 which is a whitespace entered in a keyboard. If that happens, SQL built in functions for trimming whitespaces do not work so it becomes necessary to replace the “other” whitespace characters with character 32. Then LTRIM and RTRIM will work as expected.

```
**Select [udfTrim](ColumnName) from Table**

**CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfTrim] 
(
    @StringToClean as varchar(8000)
)**
RETURNS varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN   
    --Replace all non printing whitespace characers with Characer 32 whitespace
    --NULL
    Set @StringToClean = Replace(@StringToClean,CHAR(0),CHAR(32));
    --Horizontal Tab
    Set @StringToClean = Replace(@StringToClean,CHAR(9),CHAR(32));
    --Line Feed
    Set @StringToClean = Replace(@StringToClean,CHAR(10),CHAR(32));
    --Vertical Tab
    Set @StringToClean = Replace(@StringToClean,CHAR(11),CHAR(32));
    --Form Feed
    Set @StringToClean = Replace(@StringToClean,CHAR(12),CHAR(32));
    --Carriage Return
    Set @StringToClean = Replace(@StringToClean,CHAR(13),CHAR(32));
    --Column Break
    Set @StringToClean = Replace(@StringToClean,CHAR(14),CHAR(32));
    --Non-breaking space
    Set @StringToClean = Replace(@StringToClean,CHAR(160),CHAR(32));

    Set @StringToClean = LTRIM(RTRIM(@StringToClean));
    Return @StringToClean
END
```

Answer (score 13):

You could do something brute force, such as removing the first character "manually" if it is not alphanumeric:

```
update table
    set name = rtrim(ltrim(case when name not like '[a-zA-Z0-9]%'
                                then stuff(name, 1, 1, '')
                                else name
                           end)
                    );
```

You could also search and replace that particular character:

```
update table
    set name = rtrim(ltrim(replace(name, "big dash", '')));
```

Comment: thanks gordon. Is there a way I can replicate this hex problem so that I can also try your solution on that ?

Comment: The second one works, but would not work when we don't know what the offending symbol is.

Comment: I get an error - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ')'. After removing, it works.

Comment: Btw, the first script fails for the table given here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589216/cannot-insert-value-as-is-need-answer-for-any-db-oracle-sql-server-mysql-e

Answer (score 11):

If your string has some non-unicode chars, then those need to be removed first. The functions for that are given later, taken from this link - http://iso30-sql.blogspot.com/2010/10/remove-non-printable-unicode-characters.html

First, check if there are any weird hex chars using -

```
select convert(varbinary, Name) from table
```

Then, use the code given in the link above. Note that in the usage of functions, square brackets are to be removed, otherwise the code won't work. Eg. `[@DatabaseName = 'MyDatabaseName',] [@SchemaName = 'MySchemaName',]`

After this, your strings might have some spaces which can be removed using -

```
UPDATE Table
SET Name = RTRIM(LTRIM(Name))
```

**Also NOTE that the scripts given in the above link/below will not work on the 
following table -**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Junk](
    [JunkHex] nvarchar(50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Junk] ([JunkHex]) VALUES (N'Stringğ ')
INSERT [dbo].[Junk] ([JunkHex]) VALUES (N'withħ')
INSERT [dbo].[Junk] ([JunkHex]) VALUES (N'įņvalidđ')
INSERT [dbo].[Junk] ([JunkHex]) VALUES (N'charactersŝ')
```

---

**This is the content of the link I have given above -**

Remove non-printable / Unicode characters in SQL Server 2005
A few months ago, I was upgrading some report templates from the older version of Excel (*.xls) to Excel 2007 (*.xlsx). I ran into numerous problems almost immediately when I attempted to generate the upgraded reports because the incoming data was riddled with charaters that don't play nicely with XML. The data is used for a variety of reporting purposes, so I decided to tackle the problem on the back-end by removing all but the printable ascii characters.

I started by writing a simple user function for individual strings, but I got to thinking that I may want to automate some of these cleanup tasks and ended up putting something together that allows for a bit more the flexibility. The following creates the basic string user function, along with two procedures to perform the cleanup at the column and table level:

**Note** - Each of the scripts below uses all the ones above it. So, execute all scripts in order to get all functionality.

Function: fn_npclean_string

```
use [master]
go
set ansi_nulls on
go
set quoted_identifier on
go
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_npclean_string] (
 @strIn as varchar(1000)
)
returns varchar(1000)
as
begin
 declare @iPtr as int
 set @iPtr = patindex('%[^ -~0-9A-Z]%', @strIn COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN)
 while @iPtr > 0 begin
  set @strIn = replace(@strIn COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN, substring(@strIn, @iPtr, 1), '')
  set @iPtr = patindex('%[^ -~0-9A-Z]%', @strIn COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN)
 end
 return @strIn
end
```

Procedure: sp_npclean_col

```
use [master]
go
set ansi_nulls on
go
set quoted_identifier on
go
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_npclean_col]
 @DatabaseName varchar(75) = null,
 @SchemaName varchar(75) = null,
 @TableName varchar(75),
 @ColumnName varchar(75)
as
begin
 Declare @FullTableName varchar(100)
 declare @UpdateSQL nvarchar(1000)
 if @DatabaseName is null begin
  set @DatabaseName = db_name()
 end
 if @SchemaName is null begin
  set @SchemaName = schema_name()
 end
 set @FullTableName = '[' + @DatabaseName + '].[' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @TableName + ']'
 set @UpdateSQL = 'update ' + @FullTableName + ' set [' + @ColumnName + '] = dbo.fn_npclean_string([' + @ColumnName + ']) where [' + @ColumnName + '] like ''%[^ -~0-9A-Z]%'''
 exec sp_ExecuteSQL @UpdateSQL
end
```

Procedure: sp_npclean_table

```
use [master]
go
set ansi_nulls on
go
set quoted_identifier on
go
create procedure [dbo].[sp_npclean_table] 
 @TargetDatabase varchar(75) = null,
 @TargetSchema varchar(75) = null,
 @TargetTable varchar(75)
as
begin
 declare @getColSQL nvarchar(750)
 declare @textCol CURSOR
 declare @curCol varchar(75)
 if @TargetDatabase is null begin
  set @TargetDatabase = db_name()
 end
 if @TargetSchema is null begin
  set @TargetSchema = schema_name()
 end
 set @getColSQL =
  'select sc.name
  from ' + @TargetDatabase + '.sys.columns sc
  join ' + @TargetDatabase + '.sys.types st
  on sc.system_type_id = st.system_type_id
  join ' + @TargetDatabase + '.sys.objects so
  on sc.object_id = so.object_id
  join ' + @TargetDatabase + '.sys.schemas ss
  on so.schema_id = ss.schema_id
  where
  so.type = ''U''
  and st.name in (''text'',''ntext'',''varchar'',''char'',''nvarchar'',''nchar'')
  and sc.is_rowguidcol = 0
  and sc.is_identity = 0
  and sc.is_computed = 0
  and so.name = ''' + @TargetTable + '''
  and ss.name = ''' + @TargetSchema + ''''
 set @getColSQL = 'set @inCursor = cursor for ' + @getColSQL + ' open @incursor'
 execute sp_executesql @getColSQL,N'@inCursor cursor out',@inCursor=@textCol OUT
 fetch next from @textCol into @curCol
 while @@fetch_status = 0
 begin
  exec sp_npclean_col @DatabaseName = @TargetDatabase, @SchemaName = @TargetSchema, @TableName = @TargetTable, @ColumnName = @curCol
  fetch next from @textCol into @curCol
 end
 Close @textCol
 DeAllocate @textCol
end
```

**Using these, invalid characters can be removed in the following ways:**

By String:

```
select master.dbo.fn_npclean_string('Stringğ withħ įņvalidđ charactersŝ')
```

By table column:

```
exec master.dbo.sp_npclean_col [@DatabaseName = 'MyDatabaseName',] [@SchemaName = 'MySchemaName',] @TableName = 'MyTableName',  @ColumnName = 'MyColumnName'
```

By table:

```
exec master.dbo.sp_npclean_table [@TargetDatabase = 'MyDatabaseName',] [@TargetSchema = 'MySchemaName',] @TargetTable = 'MyTableName'
```

Comment: Btw, this script fails when we create a table with the code given here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589216/cannot-insert-value-as-is-need-answer-for-any-db-oracle-sql-server-mysql-e

Comment: @InTheSKies 

+1 on the provided link and description- it worked great for me.  

One thing to edit would be the "By table column" and "By table" chunks of code at the end which still include the brackets, however.  You mentioned in the post to remove these but you left them in the provided code.  

Also, I think it's helpful to note that the second one ("By table column") depends on the first, so you actually would need to run both the first and second stored procedures even if you only want to remove the characters by table column. :)

Answer (score 3):

I use this command while updating all rows' value.
**It'll really work out.**
For your example:

```
UPDATE Table SET Name = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Name, CHAR(10), CHAR(32)), CHAR(13), CHAR(32)), CHAR(160), CHAR(32)),CHAR(9),CHAR(32))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HEX method above, or you can also use the ASCII() function to determine the ASCII code of the character in question...

```
SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING('  character string', 1, 1)) 
SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING('  character string', 2, 1))
```

The select only returns 1 value for the character you specify.  But it's helpful for determining which ASCII CHAR() value(s) you need to replace.

-Eric Isaacs

Answer (score 0):

Use this to identify the offending character:

```
select ascii(substring(' Your string with leading invisible character',1,1));
-- returns something like 160
```

Use this to replace the offending character

```
replace(' Your string with leading invisible character', char(160),'')
```

Answer (score 0):

The space character is represented in two different way one with ASCII code number 32 and another with ASCII code number 160. TRIM function will not trim the non-breaking space char.

```
DECLARE @nonbreakingspaceString VARCHAR(10) = 'String '
DECLARE @normalspaceString VARCHAR(10) = 'String '
```

Non-breaking space Char with ASCII code 160, returns 160 in below select query.

```
SELECT CHAR(160)
SELECT ascii(' ') -- Replace the non-breaking space Char with the above result, as non-breaking char is not applied here.
```

Space Char with ASCII 32, returns 32 in below select query.

```
SELECT CHAR(32)
SELECT ascii(' ')
```

String with non-breaking space ASCII code 160, returns length 7 as this does not TRIM the string

```
SELECT LEN(TRIM(@nonbreakingspaceString))
```

String with space ASCII code 32, TRIMS the string and returns length 6.

```
SELECT LEN(TRIM(@normalspaceString))
```

So when we encounter a situation were string is not getting trimmed, we can use  REPLACE as below to replace the non-breaking space char. Below code returns length of string as 6.

```
SELECT LEN(REPLACE(@nonbreakingspaceString, CHAR(160), ''))
```

Answer (score -1):

There are cases that the LTRIM RTRIM not doing what you want, to me, it happened because of the tab key when tab key inserted to a database we cant see it in our eyes in this cases trim function doesn't work.

**Try this code**

`UPDATE <TablaName>
SET NAME = CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(value, CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''))) AS VARCHAR(50))`