# Cannot insert value as is - need answer for any DB - Oracle, Sql Server, MySql etc

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

Although this is a SQL server question, but it applies to all. So, non SQL server answers are also welcome.

I am trying to create a table and enter junk values into it as shown below. SQL server removes all the junk characters from it and inserts only english characters. How do I make it allow me to insert junk characters. Its needed to test some code here - [Trim spaces in string - LTRIM RTRIM not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585914/trim-spaces-in-string-ltrim-rtrim-not-working)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Junk](
    [JunkHex] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Junk] ([JunkHex]) VALUES ('Stringğ ')
INSERT [dbo].[Junk] ([JunkHex]) VALUES ('withħ')
INSERT [dbo].[Junk] ([JunkHex]) VALUES ('įņvalidđ')
INSERT [dbo].[Junk] ([JunkHex]) VALUES ('charactersŝ')
```

Comment: What interface you use, for inserting ?

Comment: Could it be that the database collation (the character set used for string values) does not support the junk characters you are using? It is possible that the server falls back silently to empty or other character, but I am not sure if this behavior is really so. What happens if you use `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`?

Comment: Define "junk character".  Assuming that you mean "a character that is not part of the database's character set or the table's collation"?  If so, the whole point of defining those things is to ensure that characters outside of that character set don't get persisted.  If you are asking how to get around those checks, that is, at a minimum, a very database-specific question.

Comment: Works with Postgres: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/22e87/1 but not in SQL Server: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/22e87/1 most probably a characterset issue.

Comment: @OracleUser - Management Studio 2008

Comment: @Gordon's Suggestion works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating the field with the national character set and defining the constants as wide strings:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Junk](
    [JunkHex] nvarchar(50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Junk] ([JunkHex]) VALUES (N'Stringğ ')
INSERT [dbo].[Junk] ([JunkHex]) VALUES (N'withħ')
INSERT [dbo].[Junk] ([JunkHex]) VALUES (N'įņvalidđ')
INSERT [dbo].[Junk] ([JunkHex]) VALUES (N'charactersŝ')
```

You can see this work on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ff6a7/1).

Answer (score 2):

Try this will work fine:
I have changed your table name as "#t" which will be temp table.

```
CREATE TABLE #t(
            [JunkHex] [varchar](50) NULL
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
        GO

        GO
        INSERT #t([JunkHex]) VALUES ('Stringğ '),
        ('withħ'),
        ('įņvalidđ'),
        ('charactersŝ')

        Select * from #t
```

Comment: no, this does not work. It is the same as my question, except that it uses a temp table.

Comment: Have you try running it...

Comment: Firstly, It does not even need to be tried, given that you only use a temp table instead. But, I still tried it and it did not work. The question is - have you tried it in sql server ?

Comment: @InTheSkies : You have to see the answer before you comment.I clearly mentioned that I am using temp table.