# Trim undetected spaces in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

After using `Ltrim(Column name)` or `Rtrim(Column Name)` still there are undetected characters.

[image]

I tried to search the specific character with 10 characters on the table but still undetected. There are 2 extra spaces at the end of the word and trim function is not working.

Comment: `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` only remove leading and trailing spaces. If you have *other* characters, it will **not** remove them. You'll need to identify what those characters are and remove them with another method, such as by using `REPLACE`. An image of non-visible characters, however, is not going to help us help you identify them.

Comment: could you give example how to identify those other characters? I tried to check it and it is double space at the end of the word.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trim spaces in string - LTRIM RTRIM not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585914/trim-spaces-in-string-ltrim-rtrim-not-working)

Comment: Also `LEN` (which I assume you are using) doesn't count trailing spaces when determining the length of a string type value. `LEN('a     ')` would return `1`, not `7`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following user defined function (UDF)

**SQL**

```
/*
1. All invisible TAB, Carriage Return, and Line Feed characters will be replaced with spaces.
2. Then leading and trailing spaces are removed from the value. 
3. Further, contiguous occurrences of more than one space will be replaced with a single space.
*/
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_tokenize(@input VARCHAR(MAX))
   RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN 
   RETURN (SELECT CAST('<r><![CDATA[' + @input + ']]></r>' AS XML).value('(/r/text())[1] cast as xs:token?','VARCHAR(MAX)'));
END
```

**Test harness**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @mockTbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), col_1 VARCHAR(100), col_2 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockTbl (col_1, col_2)
VALUES ('  FL   ', '  Miami')
   , ('  FL   ', '  Fort       Lauderdale   ')
   , ('  NY   ', '  New           York   ')
   , ('  NY   ', '')
   , ('  NY   ', NULL);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @mockTbl;

-- remove invisible chars
UPDATE @mockTbl
SET col_1 = dbo.udf_tokenize(col_1)
, col_2 = dbo.udf_tokenize(col_2);

-- after
SELECT *, LEN(col_2) AS [col_2_len] FROM @mockTbl;
```